# Unable to access hard drive

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, mount, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to mount my external hard drive but I keep getting this error

> Unable to access “Backup Data”

```
Error mounting /dev/sdb3 at /media/root/Backup Data: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=0,gid=0,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sdb3" "/media/root/Backup Data"' exited with non-zero exit status 13: ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x43425355  size: 4096   usa_ofs: 893  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument
Actual VCN (0x8000032a58e1600) of index buffer is different from expected VCN (0x0).
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb3': Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.
 (udisks-error-quark, 0)
```

I tried to use GPARTED and Gnome-disks but it says that I will lose my data if I try to repair the hard drive.

Comment: Usually external data storages are auto-mounted just by onnecting them. Did you perform manually this mount command, and if so, then why? Doesn't your ext HDD automounts? Did it ever?

Comment: It's not me actually, it's a friend of mine. All he told me that he mounted the hard drive on Windows and copied his data to my hard drive and when he wanted to mount it again it gave him this same message I get on Ubuntu as well. And to answer your last question: Yes, it was working fine, it auto-mounts whenever I plug it, but after I gave it to my friend the problem happened.

Answer (score -1):

Use `ntfsfix` (in the `ntfs-3g` package). If it can't fix the filesystem, it can at least mark it as needing a consistency check the next time it is attached to a running Windows system (and then Windows will do the rest).

Comment: Rule #1 of data storage issues: never perform any writing operations.

Comment: I don't want to lose all my data, and performing this commands may cost me all my data loss! Isn't there any solution!